# AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm messing around with code where an AI is set to passively move around in an area near a player, until it gets close enough and starts searching for them. Once it gets even closer it starts actively chasing the player (who cannot yet move, I am not that far).

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeih8.png)

[screenshot 1 of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pMpH.png)

[screenshot 2 of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5D1M.png)

I checked over the names of the variables initialized in the player initialize but I didn't see anything spelt differently between them, I made sure that the variable actually existed. Neither of these worked.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `x` and `y` are attributes of Player instances, not the Player class itself.

Comment: You need a variable for the other player that you're chasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Player` refers to the *class* `Player`, not an individual object of that class. The class itself does not have an atteibute `x`. It is not clear in your code if `Player` is meant to be a singleton (a class with only a single instance), or if you mean to refer to a specific instance.

Comment: i apologize for my errors in stackexchange etiquette like uploading images of code/data/errors, I haven't used this in a while. Player is supposed to only be a class with a single instance. If this is rather obvious, I apologize, I'm getting back into programming after not touching it for like a year or two.

Comment: Don’t worry about it. But you’re not *using* Player as a singleton. Stuff that happens in __init__ only happens when you construct a player via `Player()`, and you don’t do that as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fully change the code so it functions properly, I'm on like 3 hours of sleep at the moment and my brain is not actively functioning.

Comment: Step 1 is to get some sleep. Step 2 is to read up on singletons. For example, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/what-is-the-best-way-of-implementing-singleton-in-python

Comment: Actually, step 2 is to edit your question so it contains actual code instead of screenshots from your IDE. Step 3 is to read up on singletons.